# Give $x,y,z>0: x^2+z^2=y^2+xy+3yz+xz$ . Find Max Value Of $P=\frac{x}{(2y+z)^2}-\frac{1}{xy(y+2z)}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Give $x,y,z>0: x^2+z^2=y^2+xy+3yz+zx$

Find Max Value Of $P=\frac{x}{(2y+z)^2}-\frac{1}{xy(y+2z)}$

Could someone give me an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

hint: when $x$ get max, P will be max.

$z^2-(3y+x)z+(x^2-y^2-xy)=0, \Delta \ge 0 \implies x \le \dfrac{13}{3}y$

now take $x=\dfrac{13}{3}y$,you can go from here.